# Query SQL update column image

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, sql-update

I'm testing the following query to update the columns in a SQL Server database, reporting the following code:

```
data1 = textbox 
data2 = TextBox2 
using ms as new MemoryStream () 
DirectCast (picturebox1.image, botmap) .save (ms currentFormat) 
image = ms.toArray () 
end using 

Dim param as SqlParameter () = _ 
new SqlParameter () {new SqlParameter ("@ data1", _ 
data1), new SqlParameter ("@ data2", data2), new SqlParameter ("@ image", image)} 
mcmd.commandText = "update set table column1 = '" + data1 + "', column2 '" + data1 + "'" 
mcmd.parameters.add ("@ image", SqlDbType.varbinary, 8000) .Value = image
```

The line of code only updates the values ​​`data1` and `data2` but the image is not updated

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `UPDATE` statement below; it doesn't looks correct at all syntactically, and you are missing `=` after `column2`

```
mcmd.commandText = "update set table column1 = '" + data1 + "', column2 '" + data1 + "'"
```

It should be

```
mcmd.commandText = "update table_name set column1 = '" + data1 + "', column2 = '" + data2 + "'"
```

Also, you have already declared parameters for the values, so use them in your `UPDATE` statement

```
mcmd.commandText = "update table_name set column1 = @data1, column2 = @data2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated the query, the date1 and date2 are updated but the image no, why?

Comment: Cause, you didn't included image in your update query. Include Image field as well in your UPDATE statement. Consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Comment: the image which I try to update before the turn into a varbinary data as you can see above, then the line: 

mcmd.parameters.add (immagine "SQlDbType.VarBinary, 8000) .Value = image 

In theory this should be the string to update the image field in the database? 

or do I put it when I use update table set?

Comment: Yes, you need to put in update statement saying `update table_name set column1 = @data1, column2 = @data2, image = @image`

Comment: plug in the string update the transformed image matrix I get the error: 

the + operator is not defined for types 'String' and 'matrix' 1-byte size

Comment: excuse me: if I plug in the string update the transformed image matrix I get the error: 

the + operator is not defined for types 'String' and 'matrix' 1-byte size

Comment: That's because `image` is most probably an array and you can't directly concat with string. Moreover, it's not part of your original question. If you have a separate question then post it separately.